# Map multiple DB columns to the same model attribute

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework-core

I am working on a ASP.NET Core (2.2) project using Entity Framework Core and Fluent API.
I would like to map two table columns (of which one is the primary key) to a single model attribute.

Let us suppose that we have this table called ***sample_table*** composed by the columns:

```
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|      Column1_PK     |     Column2      |     Column3      |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
```

I would like to map a model field to multiple columns. I guessed I could nest multiple `HasColumnName` as in the example below:

```
public class MyContext : DbContext
{
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(builder);
        builder.Entity<MyModel>().ToTable("sample_table");
        builder.Entity<MyModel>()
            .HasKey(m => m.MyId);
        builder.Entity<MyModel>()
            .Property(m => m.MyId)
            .HasColumnName("Column1_PK")
            .HasColumnName("Column2"); // I would like to map the Column1_PK and Column2 to m.MyId
        builder.Entity<MyModel>()
            .Property(m => m.OtherColumn)
            .HasColumnName("Column3");
    }
}
```

The approach above is not working.
Is there any way to achieve this funcionality?

Comment: Have you tried using data annotations? Instead of fluent API. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relational/columns#data-annotations

Comment: I think there's not a good way to do what you want (at least I'm not aware of). I've been tracking this because I also wanted to do something similar. In theory `OwnedTypes` could be used, but they don't support primary keys within the "owned type". This issue tracks what might be a feature for this https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/9906

Answer (score 0):

Will mapping it in the `MyModel` class work?

```cs
public class MyModel
{
    public string MyId
    {
        get
        {
            if (Column1_PK != Column2)
            {
                // TODO: handle if values are not equal
            }
            else
            {
                return Column1_PK;
            }
        }
        set
        {
            Column1_PK = value;
            Column2 = value;
        }
    }
    public string Column1_PK { get; private set; }
    public string Column2 { get; private set; }
}


protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
{
    builder.Entity<MyModel>()
        .HasKey(m => m.Column1_PK); // this seems to be the actual PK based on my understanding

    builder.Entity<MyModel>()
        .Ignore(m => m.MyId);
}
```

Comment: What is this kind of mapping? I've never seen it

Comment: it's just plain old OOP / C#

Comment: This should perform a string concat, right? I don't want this behaviour.
I would like them to be the same value